# How is Mocha's basic functions 'describe/before/it' implemented?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I'm somewhat new to JS, very new to Mocha, so I apologize if this is a dumb question...

I recently started working with Mocha as I'm in the early stages of a new side-project.  I have mocha installed locally by the way, `npm i mocha --save-dev`.

I start considering if I should implement portions of my project like mocha, since I'm so happy with how easy it is to get going.  Trouble is I can't figure out how they have this set up.  I've looked through some of the code on GitHub, but would like a high level summary.

This is my `test.js` file

```
const app = require('../src/app');
const assert = require('assert');

describe('my app', function(){

    it('does something cool', function(){
        assert.strictEqual(app.foo(), true);
    })
});
```

I'm confused because I don't have `const mocha = require('mocha');` in there but VS Code still recognizes identifiers like `describe` `before`, and `it`.  VS Code even tells me when I hover on `describe` that it's *var describe: Mocha.SuiteFunction*.

How is this code working, let alone with IntelliSense?  I was expecting to have to do something like `mocha.describe()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mocha loads the test files, it adds it to the `global` context.

- Seen here: [`suite.emit(EVENT_FILE_PRE_REQUIRE, global, file, self)`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/mocha.js#L308) (note the `global` argument here),
- Handled here: [`suite.on(EVENT_FILE_PRE_REQUIRE, function(context, file, mocha) {})`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/interfaces/bdd.js#L27-L47) (note that `context` is `global` from `suite.emit`)

> VS Code even tells me when I hover on `describe` that it's *var describe: Mocha.SuiteFunction*

Your project probably has `@types/mocha` package installed. Intellisense didn't come up for me until I ran `npm install --save-dev @types/mocha`.